# Zapier Webhooks + Stripe API not returning "success_url"

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, zapier

I'm attempting to retrieve the "success_url" from a charge in Stripe via Zapier.

When using the Webhook step within Zapier, I get the following error:

> The app returned "Missing required param: success_url.".

In the backend of Stripe, I'm able to view this session and confirm that it indeed does have a success_url specified, and the checkout process even brings the customer to the url correctly, but I still get this error within Zapier.

Am I missing something??

All I'm trying to do is retrieve that success_url so that I can email it to the customer after the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Which endpoint are you using to retrieve the success_url? Viewing the Stripe API docs, it seems the success_url is retrieved with a session ID:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve

The GET on the charges endpoint does not appear to return this ID:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/retrieve

Perhaps you could share a screenshot blocking off any sensitive (API keys, PII, etc.) of the request?